# I can't display array on JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SortingArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrNUm;
    }

    public void initializeArray(int arrNum[]) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arrNum[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void sortDescending(int arrNum[]) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (10); j++) {
                if (arrNum[j - 1] < arrNum[j]) {
                    temp = arrNum[j - 1];
                    arrNum[j - 1] = arrNum[j];
                    arrNum[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

// This method generates array sorted in ascending and displays the array element values
    public static void sortAscending(int arrNum[]) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (10); j++) {
                if (arrNum[j - 1] > arrNum[j]) {
                    temp = arrNum[j - 1];
                    arrNum[j - 1] = arrNum[j];
                    arrNum[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

// This method outputs the array
    public void displayArray(int[] arrNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrNum[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to look at `Arrays.toString` as a starting point

Comment: Do you get some kind of error message or what is happening running this code? Or what do you even want to see in your JOptionPane. Do you expect something like: 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, ...?